# Dropping an external file into a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyside, qtreewidget

I guess the implementation isn't quite the same for a QTreeWidget, but I'd like to be able to drop an external file, particularly an image or movie file into my QTreeWidget. I'm not trying to drag it into a specific QTreeWidgetItem, but rather just the tree as a whole. Here's my code:

```
class moTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(moTree, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                #Handle stuff here
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

The dragEnterEvent is being called, but the dropEvent is not and I'm getting the 'blocked' icon. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reimplement [QTreeWidget.mimeTypes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#mimeTypes) so that it returns a list of the [types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#details) you want to support:

```
def mimeTypes(self):
    return QtCore.QStringList([
        'text/uri-list',
        'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist',
        ])
```